# Finding Miller index

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

When a beam of electron hits a crystal and come back at some angle, how we calculate the plane from which it reflects (let us consider it reflects).
i mean what is the miller index of the plane?

Comment: Are you working in Bragg geometry.

Comment: yes. I am trying to know how the system works

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are working in Bragg geometry you will see one peak corresponding to one angle, from which you can get the spacing between crystal planes from Bragg reflection condition.

$$2d\sin\theta=n\lambda$$ 
and 
$$\lambda=\frac{h}{\sqrt{2mE}}$$ 
where $E$ is the energy of the electron.

Now you should gather the information about different peaks using $\theta, 2\theta$ diffractometer. From these peaks you will get different angle $\theta$ and hence different d values,

If you would use Laue geometry with polycrystalline sample you may get this information in single shot. you will find that

$$\sin^2(\theta) \propto  h^2+k^2+l^2.$$

Now if you know the crystal structure i.e. ratio between a b c (where abc are sides of primitive cell), you can estimate the hkl by fitting. Note that all the crystals can not be mapped by diffraction measurement. Missing/additioal peaks gives the information whether crystal is BCC or FCC etc.

I would suggest to read elements of x ray diffraction by B D cullity for deeper understanding of the estimation of crystal structure. x-ray diffraction and electron diffraction are almost similar in theory.

regards

Comment: Thanks. your answer was helpful, but what if i don't know the values of a,b, c ?and i don't even know the crystal structure !! 

okey let me try the book first